# How can I run features within a rake task in parallel?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Normally I run my tests with parallel_cucumber which runs different features in parallel using parallel_test gem. I want to setup a rake task that will run using different profiles and run the features within each task in parallel.

I have setup my Rakefile this way:

```
namespace :features do
  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:basket) do |t|
    t.profile = "basket"
  end

  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:fruits) do |t|
    t.profile = "fruits"
  end

  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:veggies) do |t|
    t.profile = "veggies"
  end
  task :all => [:basket, :fruits, :veggies]
end
```

When I run "rake features:all" it will run each task in sequence(as expected/desired) but will run the features within each task one at a time(not desired). I would like to keep each task running in sequence but would like the features within each task to run in parallel. Is this possible? If not is there a way this can be done?

As always your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) gem.  It allows you to run your features in parallel.  While the typical use case is to run all of your features, you are able to run specific rake tasks in parallel.  See the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I use that now but have not used it with a rake task.

Answer (score 1):

Rake offers multitask. You could either

1. Changing `task` to `multitask` in the rakefile:

   `multitask :all => [:basket, :fruits, :veggies]`
2. use -m option in the command line:

   `rake -m features:all`

Comment: It runs the tasks in sequence and not in parallel

Comment: It works for me even without using "multitask" explicitly (I just define an "all" task).